# Download a csv file and customize in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to download a csv file and customize with using python 3.

#### Code:

```
from urllib import request

google_url= "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1510328010&period2=1512920010&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=IpXue1sAr6r"

def download_stock_data (csv_url):

    response = request.urlopen (csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'goog.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

download_stock_data (google_url)
```

#### Error:

```
C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/ihsan.iyigun/PycharmProjects/untitled3/new.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ihsan.iyigun/PycharmProjects/untitled3/new.py", line 17, in <module>
    download_stock_data (google_url)
  File "C:/Users/ihsan.iyigun/PycharmProjects/untitled3/new.py", line 6, in download_stock_data
    response = request.urlopen (csv_url)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ihsan.iyigun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I debug or fix this?

Comment: The error is for permissions, you do not have authorization to access that resource, that is referred to with error 401, I recommend you use the following library: yahoo-finance: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the web page you're trying to access requires authentication.  If so, you'll have to figure out how to programmatically log in to the site before going to the page you want.

Trying to manually go to that URL, I get the following in my browser:

```
{
    "finance": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "description": "Invalid cookie"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First Download your CSV file and put it to a local drive on mycomputer and then go to the Run these codes to load your csv file:

```
import csv
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines=csv.reader(open(filename,"r"))
    dataset=list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i]=[float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
filename='E:\dataset.csv'
dataset=loadCsv(filename)
print("Loaded data file {} with {} rows".format(filename,len(dataset)))
print("First Record{}".format(dataset[1]))
```

Then open cmd follow these commands ->

> C:\Users>cd..
>   C:>cd Python34
>   C:\Python34>python.exe e:NB.pyimport csv

Now you can get the result.